# Vue Provide & Inject undefined on component load

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

### Situation

I am trying to use the Options API for the Provide & Inject capabilities of Vue, so that the `header.vue` component can provide data to the `container-nav.vue` component (see component hierarcy). However, when the data is injected, it is undefined on initial load.

**Current Component Hierarchy:**

- header.vue > header-nav-menu.vue > container-nav.vue

## Attempt 1 - header.vue (grandparent)

In this component, I am fetching the following string `'/'` inside `Provide() {}`, from pinia (storeCommon).

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import parentStore from '@/store'

export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
        // Should not have access to this.navHome -> undefined (loads before options API)
        console.log("1. Calling setup in Header")

        const storeCommon = parentStore()
        return { storeCommon }
    },
    beforeCreate() {
        // Should not have access to this.navHome -> undefined (loads before options API)
        console.log("2. Calling beforeCreate in Header")
    },
    provide() {
        console.log("3. Calling provide in Header")
        return {
            navHome: this.storeCommon.textualData[0]?.navigation.links.home
        }
    },
    created() {
        // Should have access to this.navHome -> '/' (loads after options API)
        console.log("9. Calling beforeCreate in Container Nav: ", this.$refs.navHome)
    },
    mounted() {
        // Should have access to this.navHome -> '/' (loads after options API)
        console.log("8. Calling beforeCreate in Container Nav: ", this.$refs.navHome)
    }
})
```

## Attempt 1 - container-nav.vue (child)

In this component, I am injecting `navHome` that was provided by the `header.vue` component.

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
    inject: [ 'navHome' ],
    setup() {
        // Should not have access to this.navHome -> undefined (loads before options API)
        console.log("4. Calling setup in Container Nav")
    },
    beforeCreate() {
        // Should not have access to this.navHome -> undefined (loads before options API)
        console.log("5. Calling beforeCreate in Container Nav")
    },
    created() {
        // Should have access to this.navHome -> '/' (loads after options API)
        console.log("6. Calling beforeCreate in Container Nav: ", this.$refs.navHome)
    },
    mounted() {
        // Should have access to this.navHome -> '/' (loads after options API)
        console.log("7. Calling beforeCreate in Container Nav: ", this.$refs.navHome)
    }
})
```

## Attempt 1 - testing

Running the following code with the console.logs produces the following result:

```
1. Calling setup in Header                                
2. Calling beforeCreate in Header: undefined              -> Correct
3. Calling Provide in Header
4. Calling setup in Container Nav
5. Calling beforeCreate in Container Nav: undefined       -> Correct
6. Calling created in Container Nav: undefined            -> Incorrect (should be '/')
7. Calling mounted in Container Nav: undefined            -> Incorrect (should be '/')
8. Calling mounted in Header: undefined                   -> Incorrect (should be '/')
9. Calling created in Header: undefined                   -> Incorrect (should be '/')
```

---

## Attempt 2 - header.vue (grandparent)

Using the same code as before & Options API, apart from using the `setup` with `provide`.

```
import { defineComponent, provide } from 'vue'
import parentStore from '@/store'

setup() {
    // 1. Tried this way
    const navLinkHome = parentStore().getTextualData[0]?.navigation.links.home
    const navHome = provide('navHome', navLinkHome)

    // 2. Tried this way
    const navHome = provide('navHome', parentStore().getTextualData[0]?.navigation.links.home)

    return {
        // 1 & 2
        navHome
        
        // And also this way
        navHome: provide('navHome', parentStore().getTextualData[0]?.navigation.links.home)
    }
}
```

## Attempt 2 - container-nav.vue (child)

```
import { defineComponent, inject } from 'vue'

setup() {
    const navHome = inject('navHome')

    return {
        navHome

        // Tried this too, but same as above just longer
        navHome: navHome
    }
}
```

## Attempt 2 - testing

Running the following code with the console.logs produces the following result:

```
1. Calling setup in Header                                
2. Calling beforeCreate in Header: undefined              -> Correct
3. Calling setup in Container Nav
4. Calling beforeCreate in Container Nav: undefined       -> Correct
5. Calling created in Container Nav: undefined            -> Incorrect (should be '/')
6. Calling mounted in Container Nav: undefined            -> Incorrect (should be '/')
7. Calling mounted in Header: undefined                   -> Incorrect (should be '/')
8. Calling created in Header: undefined                   -> Incorrect (should be '/')
```

### Confusions

- First of all, I noticed when using the `provide() {}` Options API within `header.vue`, and trying to reference `navHome`. I could not use `this.navHome` inside the created or mounted methods. I would get an error saying that it did not exist on type `CreateComponentPublicInstance`. To combat this problem, I instead used `this.$refs.navHome` - not even sure if this is the right thing to do.
- Secondly, when using `inject: [ 'navHome' ]` inside the `container-nav.vue` component, I could not access it using `this.navHome`. Again, I could only access it using `this.$refs.navHome`.

HOWEVER.

- When using Provide inside the setup method of `header.vue` and Inject inside the setup method of `container-nav.vue`, I could access `navHome` using `this.navHome`. Not sure why it does this.

Comment: Please keep the question as short as possible because we are all lazy people

Comment: I didn't know how to explain it in short and for people to understand. But, I will keep that in mind for next time. @Duannx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to ensure that `parentStore().getTextualData[0]?.navigation.links.home` has the value `"/"` at the time the parent provides it because it is not a reactive object
- Or you can provide a reactive object like that:

```js
const navLinkHome = computed(()=> parentStore().getTextualData[0]?.navigation.links.home)
const navHome = provide('navHome', navLinkHome)
```

- `this.$refs.navHome` is the wrong way, `this.navHome` should work. However, I recommend you use [the composition API style](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#inject)
- I'm curious that, you already have the pinia store, why do you need to use provide/inject at all?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. So, the value '/' that I am getting from the store is a static one, so does it make a difference to use the reactive 'computed(() => parentStore.getTextualData[0]?navigation.links.home)'? 

Also, I wanted to retrieve data in the header only, so all data retrieving is done in one file. Then I can pass the data on. I could just call the parent or child stores directly in the files that need them, but I wanted to avoid doing it that way because of reusable components.

Comment: @Dylan There is a slight difference when using computed. As I said you have to ensure that `this.storeCommon.textualData[0]?.navigation.links.home` has the value `/` at the time you provide it. Otherwise, you will provide an undefined value. Computed will solve that problem because it is auto updated

Comment: Actually provide, inject is not a recommended way to pass value from parent to child in case you already have state management like pinia/vuex. Because it makes your app harder to maintain when you have two places manage the state and share between components (pinia and parent provide)

Comment: Interesting. You make a good point there. I suppose if I already have a main state, I don't necessarily need provide & inject